# How to open files, one by one, using cmd?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I have a large list of files, which I would like to open with their default program. However, opening them all in one go would be rather straining for my computer (as it opens a single instance of the program per file).

Instead, I would like to open them all, one by one, and have the next one automatically open as soon as I close the current one. I know I can do

```
dir *.ext /B
```

to get a list of files. I can also do

```
start /WAIT somefile.ext
```

to open the file, blocking the command prompt until I close it again. But I don't know how I can combine these two into a working loop.

Comment: This would be far easier to do with a Powershell script than batch

Comment: `gci *.ext | % { Start-Process $_.FullName -Wait }` in PowerShell

Answer (score 2):

In command line:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %x IN ('dir *.ext /B') do ( start /WAIT "%x" )
```

In batch file - double percent signs.